# PHP - How to extract a number from the string?

Tags: php, regex

I have a string in the pattern similar to:

`john.smith 9.5 9.49296 Active john.s@site.com +123456789`

and I just want to echo "9.5" out of it which is next to "smith" using PHP.

**Update:**

sorry guys...just noticed that it is an xml file, couldn't see properly in safari, checked in firefox and it is displayed as:

```
<GetUserInfo>
<Customer>john.smith</Customer>
<Balance>9.5</Balance>
<SpecificBalance>9.49296</SpecificBalance>
<Status>False</Status>
<EmailAddress>john.s@site.com</EmailAddress>
<Phone>+1234567890</Phone>
</GetUserInfo>
```

Now what would be the php code to echo "9.5"

Thanks for your earlier answers...

Comment: so you need to parse this xml with php and get the Balance out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work

```
<?php
$string = "<GetUserInfo>
<Customer>john.smith</Customer>
<Balance>9.5</Balance>
<SpecificBalance>9.49296</SpecificBalance>
<Status>False</Status>
<EmailAddress>john.s@site.com</EmailAddress>
<Phone>+1234567890</Phone>
</GetUserInfo>";

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);

echo  $xml->Balance;

?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try splitting on whitespace (seem to be delimited by that)

```
$parts = preg_split('/\s+/', $input);
print $parts[1];
```

Answer (score 3):

a quick and durty way

```
<?php
$string="john.smith 9.5 9.49296 Active john.s@site.com +123456789";
$array = explode(" ",$string);
echo $array[1];
?>
```

Comment: I wish i knew regular expresions, I am sure there is a better way

Comment: If it's following the same pattern every time, the method we both selected (at the same time) works just fine.

Comment: well yes if the string format stays the same, I can't think of anything else

Answer (score 1):

```
$string="john.smith 9.5 9.49296 Active john.s@site.com +123456789";

$array=explode(" ",$string);
```

Then your number would be:

```
echo $array[1];
```